# Difference init a matrix 2d

Tags: python

I use two ways to init a 2d matrix in python. The method for answer = [[0] * n] * m is incorrect, while the second method is correct.
I do not know why.

```
m = len(matrix)
n = len(matrix[0])

# answer = [[0] * n] * m  # create memo table
answer = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)] # create memo table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand seeing this example

```
m = 3
n = 4

# Method 1: Incorrect way
incorrect = [[0] * n] * m

# Change one element
incorrect[0][0] = 1

print(incorrect)
# Output: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]

# Method 2: Correct way
correct = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)]

# Change one element
correct[0][0] = 1

print(correct)
# Output: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```